# Adding hyperlinks to one column

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to make hyperlinks in the first column on the condition that value in the cell begins with 'W'.

It seemed to work until I moved the script from Sheet object to ThisWorkbook.

Since then when I try to copy some cells from another worksheet and paste them to active worksheet, everything what I copied is pasted as hyperlink, no matter what column or value it is. What's more, if I try to type anything in the row where the first cell is linked, the default typing mode is in the hyperlink style.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells2 As Range
Set KeyCells2 = Range("A:A")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Count = 1 Then 'this one was meant to be a fix but it didn't change a thing
        If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "W" Then
            link = "http://<mylink>" & Target.Value
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Target, link
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Target.Address)` ? It's not qualified. Would `Target` (which is) not do?

Comment: Also, `KeyCells2 = Range("A:A")` isn't qualified.

Comment: @CLR what does it mean 'not qualified'? How to pick every cell in column A then?

Comment: Not qualified : you've told it to use Range ("A:A"), but you're expecting Excel to 'guess' which *sheet*, which *workbook* etc. you're referring to when you don't tell it specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think it will do what you need:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells2 As Range
    Dim targetcell As Range
    Set KeyCells2 = Application.Intersect(Sh.Range("A:A"), Target, Sh.UsedRange)
    If Not KeyCells2 Is Nothing Then
        For Each targetcell In KeyCells2
            If Left(targetcell.Value, 1) = "W" Then
                link = "http://my.link." & targetcell.Value
                Sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=targetcell, Address:=link
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: with usage of your function everything is pasted properly when copying the sheet but then whole application crashes...

Comment: I've changed the code to only run on the intersection of A:A, the `UsedRange` and the pasted output. This should mean the code only runs on the smallest possible set of cells.